# Where and how to reference composite MVP components?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, gui, user-interface, mvp

I am learning about the MVP (Model-View-Presenter) Passive View flavour of MVC. I intend to expose events from view interfaces rather than using the observer pattern to remove explicit coupling with presenter.

**Context:** Windows Forms / Client-Side JavaScript.

I am led to believe that the MVP (or indeed MVC in general) pattern can be applied at various levels of a user interface ranging from the main "Window" to an embedded "Text Field". For instance, the model to the text field is probably just a string whereas the model to the "Window" contains application specific view state (like a persons name which resides within the contained text field).

Given a more complex scenario:

- Documentation viewer which contains:

  - TOC navigation pane
  - Document view
  - Search pane

Since each of these 4 user interface items are complex and can be reused elsewhere it makes sense to design these using MVP.

Given that each of these user interface items comprises of 3 components; which component should be nested? where? who instantiates them?

**Idea #1 - Embed View inside View from Parent View**

```
public class DocumentationViewer : Form, IDocumentationViewerView {
    public DocumentationViewer() {
        ...

        // Unclear as to how model and presenter are injected...
        TocPane = new TocPaneView();
    }
    protected ITocPaneView TocPane { get; private set; }
}
```

**Idea #2 - Embed Presenter inside View from Parent View**

```
public class DocumentationViewer : Form, IDocumentationViewerView {
    public DocumentationViewer() {
        ...

        // This doesn't seem like view logic...
        var tocPaneModel = new TocPaneModel();
        var tocPaneView = new TocPaneView();
        TocPane = new TocPanePresenter(tocPaneModel, tocPaneView);
    }
    protected TocPanePresenter TocPane { get; private set; }
}
```

**Idea #3 - Embed View inside View from Parent Presenter**

```
public class DocumentationViewer : Form, IDocumentationViewerView {
    ...

    // Part of IDocumentationViewerView:
    public ITocPaneView TocPane { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentationViewerPresenter {
    public DocumentationViewerPresenter(DocumentationViewerModel model, IDocumentationViewerView view) {
        ...

        var tocPaneView = new TocPaneView();
        var tocPaneModel = new TocPaneModel(model.Toc);
        var tocPanePresenter = new TocPanePresenter(tocPaneModel, tocPaneView);
        view.TocPane = tocPaneView;
    }
}
```

**Some better idea...**

Answer (score 0):

After some thought it seems like the following approach might be beneficial whereby each inner control is represented by a facade which constructs the presenter, view and its model and exposes the relevant methods:

[image: Class diagram of concept]

I would love to know what others think about this idea...

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel like you missed an obvious solution. Maybe I'm missing something here, but why doesn't your form implement all three interfaces? I don't see the need to try to keeping trances of the views inside of another view.

```
public class DocumentationViewer : 
    Form, IDocumentationViewerView, ITocPaneView, ISearchView {

    public DocumentationViewer() {
        var docPresenter = new DocumentPresenter(this);
        var tocPresenter = new TocPresenter(this);
        //...
    }
```